# Execute batch command only in first level subfolders

Tags: powershell, batch-file, subdirectory

I want to execute this code only in all first level subfolders.

```
@echo off

powershell.exe "$o = Get-Content -Raw .\manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json; '{0} {1} - Microsoft Flight Simulator {2}' -f $o.creator, $o.title, $o.version | Set-Content ('version_{0}_msfs.txt' -f (-split $o.title)[0])"
```

Can i do this inside the batch file?
There is a manifest.json in file in each first level subfolder of the current folder. I want to run the batchfile from the current folder. A PowerShell part of the command will be good.

Comment: Are you saying that there is a `manifest.json` in each child directory of the current directory, (or each child directory beneath the batch file)? Please clarify, and also please clarify if you want to do this using the PowerShell part of the command, or prior to it within the batch file. _(The former makes more sense)._

Comment: Yes there is a manifest.json in file in each first level subfolder of the current folder.

A PowerShell part of the command will be good.

Comment: First of all it would be preferable, if you were to clarify your question parameters within the question body itself, not simply in the comments. Next, your current folder is not defined anywhere! how is it to be determined? You should also explain to us the possible methods of invoking this script, which is equally important. You should use the search facility at the top of the page to locate powershell questions and answers which already perform such tasks, rather than expecting us to essentially code your task for you. _(You are not the first person to have ever needed to limit recursion)._

Comment: I did a search unfortunately I didn't find anything that worked, but I would be happy if you would point me to the right answer (link).

Comment: Show us the code that didn't work. Include along side it a description of what does and/or doesn't work as expected, include any output and show us before and after directory tree structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a working code:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

REM Retrieve Parent Folder
set parentfolder=%cd%

REM Retrieve Subfolders
set i=0
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad *') do (
  set /a i+=1
  set "folder!i!=%%F"
)

REM Loop Through Sub Folders
for /l %%N in (1 1 %i%) do (
cd %parentfolder%\!folder%%N!
Powershell.exe "$o = Get-Content -Raw .\manifest.json | ConvertFrom-Json; '{0} {1} - Microsoft Flight Simulator {2}' -f $o.creator, $o.title, $o.package_version | Set-Content ('version_{0}_msfs.txt' -f (-split $o.title)[0]).ToLower()"
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).